# How to fix a widget to the right side of a ListView on Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, scroll, responsive-design, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have a Flutter Web application where I need to show a widget on the right side of a ListView when I click an item and this widget should always be visible on screen. I can achieve my objective puting both on a Row and using a scrollable only for the ListView, but that requires the ListView to be wrapped by a widget with defined height.

Defining a container with height to wrap the ListView breaks the responsiveness when I resize the browser, as the container doesn't fit the height of the screen.

I thought of using the shrinkWrap property of the ListView so I don't have to wrap it in a widget with predefined height, but that makes the whole Row scrollable vertically, eventually causing the widget to leave the viewport.

I would appreciate if somebody knows how could I keep this right side widget fixed on screen so I can achieve my objective without losing responsiveness.

Here's something similitar to what I've got so far:

```
class PageLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageLayout({Key? key, required this.items}) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> items;

  @override
  State<PageLayout> createState() => _PageLayoutState();
}

class _PageLayoutState extends State<PageLayout> {
  final rightSideWidget = Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
      ),
      height: 200);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.49,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                  ),
                  height: 200,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      widget.items[index],
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                itemCount: widget.items.length,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(child: rightSideWidget),
          ],
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

I want rightSideWidget to be always centered on screen or follow the scroll.

Comment: have your tried an expanded(Row(children[]) in a column

Comment: Share some design or video for more explain?)

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Added some code to the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your screen into two sections, right section and left section; thereby being able to control behaviour of widgets in both sections.

- Divide the overall screen into 2 proportional sections using a *Row*
  widget
- Put this Row widget inside a *Container* with height equal to screen height for preserving responsiveness | Use MediaQuery to get current height of page
- Now left hand section can individually scroll, and on click of any option from this section you can define behaviour for right section; while keeping the left section constant throughout page lifecycle